# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'split' in python odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I need to get the entered name in odoo model and get the first letters of each word in upper case. Ex: MTA Flushing from that I need to create MF as output. I tried it. But it gives the error "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'split' "
Here is my code

```
my_name     = self.env['my_details'].search([('id', '=',so_id )]).name
    my_d_name   = "".join([i[0].upper() for i in depot_name.split()])
```

Any idea to solve this???

Answer (score 0):

`i[0]` is False for some value in your database.

This should work:

```
my_d_name = "".join([i[0].upper() for i in depot_name.split() if i[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.. 
In my case first have to convert the name that searched into string and then we can apply the code without getting errors.

```
my_name     = self.env['my_details'].search([('id', '=',so_id )]).name
str_name    = str(my_name)
my_d_name   = "".join([i[0].upper() for i in my_name.split()])
```